# How can I programmatically detect that a mac app has "beachballed"?

Tags: user-interface, macos

I would like to create an application that will monitor apps running on my machine, and respond to situations where an application has beachballed. Is it possible (using any of the various OSX programming tools -- I'll teach myself Objective-C for this) to detect whether this has happened? If so, can someone give me a short code sample that does so?

Comment: I had to look this up ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinning_wait_cursor
I suggest - look at how the Windows Task manager determines whether the program is responsive or not, and apply a similar algorithm. However, I do not think you can tell a difference between a very slow and an unresponsive program. I'd be happy if someone corrects me.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid I don't the actual classes or functions involved, but I can give you an outline of the process.

First, understand that every Application (perhaps every Window) has an event queue backing it.  Each is serviced by a thread that just pops an event* off the queue, does some processing, and then returns to waiting for the next event.  A "beachball" comes up (when forced by the system) when the event queue isn't getting serviced quickly enough.  A "frozen" event queue implies that an application locked up when responding to some event in the past.

Now - outside of debugging contexts - you shouldn't be able to reach into another application and fiddle with a thread's event queue to see if its getting serviced.  **But** what you could do instead is periodically post an event that would illicit a response, and if ever that response doesn't come you know the application is "locked up".

This constitutes polling, so be wary of the performance implications.

<sub>*Events are things like key down, key up, mouse moved, repaint, and so on.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Besides the WindowServer itself, the other system components that I know of that can detect unresponsiveness are the force quit dialog, spindump (which collects sampling profiles of applications while they are unresponsive), and Activity Monitor (presumably via its pmTool privileged subprocess). Perhaps running `strings` on pmTool might provide hints about what system calls to use?

Note that none of these evidently does its job by polling, because no application is ever detected as unresponsive *until it fails to respond to an event* — if an application hangs/does a lot of computation without checking its event queue, *but it receives no events during that time*, then it is not reported as unresponsive.

Comment: Your logic is flawed.  If an application does alot of processing but receives no events than it **is not hung** as it is responding to events as quickly as they are coming in.